# RegEx for preg_match_all in PHP

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

This is my string ($string):

```
swatch: http://abc.com/not_this_one.jpg,
zoom:[
  'http://abc.com/aa.jpg'
],
large:[

  bbbbbbbbbbb'
],
swatch: http://abc.com/not_this_one.jpg,
zoom:[
  'http://abc.com/bb.jpg',

  'http://abc.com/cc.jpg'
],
large:[

  http://abc.com/also_not_this_one.jpg'
],
```

I would like to match `http://abc.com/aa.jpg`, `http://abc.com/bb.jpg`, and `http://abc.com/cc.jpg` by using `preg_match_all()`. How can I do that?

Comment: can fields other than zoom contain urls?

Comment: If this is JSON, please search for parsing JSON in PHP...

Comment: urls would exist in other fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/http:\/\/abc\.com\/(?:aa|bb|cc)\.jpg/', $string, $matches);
```